# Time Calculation in php

Tags: php

I need to get the difference between these 2 valuse in php

```
1 = ** 12:10:am **

2 = ** 10:11:pm **
```

Comment: you can turn the times into seconds and get the difference

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

**Subtract time: *(hours with minutes)***

```
function subtractTime($initialHour, $finalHour){
  return (date("H:i", strtotime("00:00") + strtotime($finalHour) - strtotime($initialHour)));
}
```

**Subtract time: *(hours with minutes and seconds)***

```
function subtractTime($initialHour, $finalHour){
  return (date("H:i:s", strtotime("00:00:00") + strtotime($finalHour) - strtotime($initialHour)));
}
```

**Sum time:**

```
function sumTime($initialHour, $finalHour) {
  $h = date('H', strtotime($finalHour));
  $m = date('i', strtotime($finalHour));
  $s = date('s', strtotime($finalHour));
  $tmp = $h." hour ".$m." min ".$s." second";
  $sumHour = $initialHour." + ".$tmp;
  $newTime = date('H:i:s', strtotime($sumHour));
  return $newTime;
}
```

Comment: if i enter the value like this $initialHour = "12:10:pm";
$finalHour  = "10:10:am"; i get the answer 00:00 ..?

Comment: not working with this time $initialHour = "10:00:am";
$finalHour  =  "9:00:pm";

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [DateTime::diff](http://php.net/manual/en/datetime.diff.php) or [strtotime](http://php.net/manual/de/function.strtotime.php)

Answer (score 0):

heres something that might help

```
$future = strtotime('21 July 2013');
$timefromdb = //source time you have to define
$timeleft = $future-$timefromdb;
$daysleft = round((($timeleft/24)/60)/60);
```

Comment: hi i need to need to get the difference between the time not by date sir sorry... but the above code may help me later but now i need to get the time val

Answer (score 0):

```
function timeToMinutes($time) {
$time = explode(':', $time);

return (($time[2]=='pm')?($time[0]+12):$time[0])*60+$time[1];
}

$diff = timeToMinutes('10:11:pm') - timeToMinutes('12:10:am');

echo $diff; //difference in minutes
```