# Calculate Total hours

Tags: php

I have a small issue while calculating sum of total hours

My working hours is like:

```
Day1 - 12:23 Hours
Day2 - 11:43 Hours
Day3 - 10:18 Hours
```

How can I get it by php?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just add them like this:

```
$day1hours = "12:23";
$day2hours = "11:43";
$day1 = explode(":", $day1hours);
$day2 = explode(":", $day2hours);

$totalmins = 0;
$totalmins += $day1[0] * 60;
$totalmins += $day1[1];
$totalmins += $day2[0] * 60;
$totalmins += $day2[1];

$hours = $totalmins / 60;
$minutes = $totalmins % 60;

$totalhours = "$hours.$minutes";
```

It is quite elaborate like this, but it just to show the idea: calculate back to minutes, add minutes together, then calculate back to hours.

Note that PHP has quite extensive support for dates and times. Consider using that: http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.datetime.php

Answer (score 1):

**This technique will give exact total hours and minutes.
The above answer gives me 1.25.15 when i add 00:30 and 00:45**

```
<?php
$hourMin = array("00:30","00:45"); //an Multiple Hour:Minutes array
$hours = 0;
$mins  = 0;
  foreach($hourMin as $val)
  {
      $explodeHoursMins = explode(':',$val);
      $hours += $explodeHoursMins[0];
      $mins  += $explodeHoursMins[1];
  }

  $minToHours =  date('H:i', mktime(0,$mins)); //Calculate Hours From Minutes
  $explodeMinToHours = explode(':',$minToHours);
  $hours += $explodeMinToHours[0];
  $finalMinutes = $explodeMinToHours[1];
  echo $hours." : ".$finalMinutes;
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you use this function to calculate time calculation then it will work

```
function sumTime($initialHour, $finalHour) {
    $h = date('H', strtotime($finalHour));
    $m = date('i', strtotime($finalHour));
    $s = date('s', strtotime($finalHour));
    $tmp = $h." hour ".$m." min ".$s." second";
    $sumHour = $initialHour." + ".$tmp;
    $newTime = date('H:i:s', strtotime($sumHour));
    return $newTime;
 };
```

For more explanation refer this link: [Time Calculation in php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12163071/time-calculation-in-php)